# Make Entry Widget Active

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change my window so that the Entry Widget is "active": without clicking in the widget, you can type and it goes directly into the box (same as IDLE's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> window --- when the window opens, without having to click into the Entrybox, you can type into it).

I tried using `entry.icursor()`:

```
from Tkinter import *
class GetFileName:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.entryFrame = Frame(self.frame)
        self.fEntry = Entry(self.entryFrame, width = 50, justify = CENTER)
        self.fEntry.icursor(0) # thought this would make it "active"
        # a bunch of other widgets
        self.fEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.entryFrame.grid(row = 1)
        self.frame.grid()

root = Tk(className = ' Module Opener')
app = GetFileName(root)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I fix this so that it is the active window? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `focus_set` on the entry widget.